# TensorFlow: Build error boringssl

Tags: python, tensorflow

Platform: **Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS**

**CPU Build**

Python Version: **Python 2.7.12**

GCC Version: **5.4.0**

Followed the installation instructions specified [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources).

I'm building without conda or virtualenv.

Ran the command:

`bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package --cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" --verbose_failures`

Received the following error log:

```
ERROR: /root/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD:101:1: no such package '@boringssl//': java.io.IOException: Error downloading [http://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/google/boringssl/archive/e3860009a091cd1bd2bc189cdbc3c6d095abde84.tar.gz, https://github.com/google/boringssl/archive/e3860009a091cd1bd2bc189cdbc3c6d095abde84.tar.gz] to /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/efb88f6336d9c4a18216fb94287b8d97/external/boringssl/e3860009a091cd1bd2bc189cdbc3c6d095abde84.tar.gz: Checksum was a9a3673b1f7bd80ef563e9de1d9ccdb5126dc0cce6377977009092148993c4fe but wanted 02f5950f93c4fd3691771c07c9d04cf2999ab01383ff99da345249e93b0fcfb2 and referenced by '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:licenses'

ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed; build aborted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the **sha256** value to `"a9a3673b1f7bd80ef563e9de1d9ccdb5126dc0cce6377977009092148993c4fe"` in `tensorflow/workspace.bzl` around line 585 as suggested [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12984)